Bendixon theorem and phase plane method
in order to prove existence of travelling waves for fisher kpp eq in case $2 \leq c$ i read paper of C.J.H. Jonkhout(i put the libk above)enter link description here and i understand his method but i have problem wit fixed point $(1,0)$  in particular the following  part :
Let $\omega$ be the $\omega$-limit set of the orbit on the unstable manifold of $(1,0)$. (See \cite{Meiss2007}, Paragraph 4.9 for the definition of an $\omega$-limit set). The orbit on the part of unstable manifold left of $(1,0)$ cannot exit $OAB$. Therefore, $\omega$ is contained in the bounded set $OAB$, and, thus, not empty, compact, and connected. Therefore, the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem \cite{Teschl2012} Thm 7.16 applies.
The Poincaré-Bendixson theorem implies that $\omega$ must either be a fixed point, a periodic orbit, or a set of heteroclinic orbits, homoclinic orbits, and fixed points. Let $(\phi^*, \psi^*)$ be a solution that lies on the part of the unstable manifold of $(1,0)$ that lies strictly left of $(1,0)$. Since we have $\phi' > 0$ inside $OAB$, $\phi^*$ is monotone. The first coordinate of the solution $\phi^*$ is also bounded by $OAB$, thus, as a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem, it has a limit. By the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem this limit must be the first coordinate of a fixed point. The limit is not equal to one, and, since there are only two fixed points, it is equal to zero.
Note that $\lim_{t \to -\infty}(\phi(t), \psi(t)) = (1, 0)$ and $\lim_{t \to +\infty}(\phi(t), \psi(t)) = (0, 0)$. Therefore, the wave profile function $\phi^*$ of the traveling wave satisfies $\lim_{\xi \to +\infty} \phi^*(\xi) = 0$ and $\lim_{\xi \to -\infty} \phi^*(\xi) = 1$."
why we cant have homocline or hetrocline orbit i know that we cant have periodoc orbit using Bendixon criteria
